# How to start all TBB continue_nodes which have no dependencies

Tags: c++, tbb, tbb-flow-graph

With TBB you can make a nice DAG of tasks and it can automatically run them in parallel. [Example from the documentation](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/tbb_userguide/Dependence_Graph.html):

```
typedef continue_node< continue_msg > node_t;
typedef const continue_msg & msg_t;

int main() {
  tbb::flow::graph g;
  node_t A(g, [](msg_t){ a(); } );
  node_t B(g, [](msg_t){ b(); } );
  node_t C(g, [](msg_t){ c(); } );
  node_t D(g, [](msg_t){ d(); } );
  node_t E(g, [](msg_t){ e(); } );
  node_t F(g, [](msg_t){ f(); } );
  make_edge(A, B);
  make_edge(B, C);
  make_edge(B, D);
  make_edge(A, E);
  make_edge(E, D);
  make_edge(E, F);
  A.try_put( continue_msg() );
  g.wait_for_all();
  return 0;
}
```

That works fine, however it assumes I have some well-known root node and all nodes are dependants of that node. What if I have some more generic network that might have multiple root nodes?

```
int main() {
  tbb::flow::graph g;

  // Imagine a function did this but in a generic way:      
  node_t A(g, [](msg_t){ a(); } );
  node_t B(g, [](msg_t){ b(); } );
  node_t C(g, [](msg_t){ c(); } );
  node_t D(g, [](msg_t){ d(); } );
  node_t E(g, [](msg_t){ e(); } );
  node_t F(g, [](msg_t){ f(); } );
  make_edge(A, B);
  make_edge(B, C);
  make_edge(D, E);

  // Now how do I now do this?
  A.try_put( continue_msg() );
  D.try_put( continue_msg() );
  F.try_put( continue_msg() );

  g.wait_for_all();
  return 0;
}
```

I hope that example is clear - basically I have a load of tasks, but the dependencies between them are dynamic so they might end up not depending on each other at all. How do I say to TBB: "Ok I want all these tasks run."

(Obviously I can manually count the number of dependencies for each task but I'm asking if TBB does that already.)

Edit: To be clear I'm asking if there is a function that *automatically* starts all the root nodes. Obviously I can do it manually - that's what the example above does!

Comment: There is no problem with several "root nodes" since they are all equal and the task is created and run for each `try_put` calls, even though `g.wait_for_all` haven't yet executed. The `graph` object handles the references for all nodes. So, when all nodes are processed and there is no work in the graph, `wait_for_all()` serves as a synchronization point and will return. You can even make new edges during the graph processing.

Comment: Yes I know. My question is not "how can I start multiple root nodes" it is "is there a function to *automatically* find all the root nodes and start them".

Comment: Then, unfortunately, there is no such built-in functionality in the Flow Graph.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a misunderstanding about `flow::graph` itself. You must specify dependencies programmatically by adding arcs between nodes. You `try_put` to the first node of the graph to start it. This is the only way to start a graph.

If you have external events that you want to trigger a graph to run, you must create a listener to that event which `try_puts` to start the graph.

You can create a `multifunction_node` that never returns, which you can have looking for events and sending messages, but this is poor TBB design. You would be permanently locking a TBB task to that multifunction_node, a no-no. And you still have to `try_put` something to the `multifunction_node` to start it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I want a function that *automatically* finds `A`, `D`, and `F` and starts them.